# How can I make a div having more than 4 corners

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have to make a `div` using HTML and CSS only but not using any background image with more than 4 corners.

[image: i want t make exactly this thing using html and css]

How can I do it?

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: I am using curved image in the main div with the absolute property with css style="right:0; top:0";

Comment: Depends on what you're aiming for, you could use a web font to accomplish that. Example: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_folder

Comment: If the upper part is intended to hold actual **content** (like text) then this is not possible *with a single div*. HTML elements are rectangular and **only** rectangular.

Comment: @Talent Runners  Can you explain why are you giving a bounty. Isn't any of the answers ok for you ?

Comment: @Paulie_D It's **is** possible with single div and you can add content to upper part. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45122149/1548895). But regarding that HTML elements are always rectangular you are right.

Comment: @vals Although Abhishek's answer is good and worked for OP, but christo's answer worked for me and it's not been highlited much, so I just want to award bounty to his/her answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `pseudo-element` and some css shape tricks to achieve this.

```css
.folder {
  width: 190px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #888;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.folder:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="folder"></div>
```

Comment: Try setting `background-image` to your body. [christo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39889797/1548895) is better because if `div`'s parent (e.g. body) has some background, this background won't be overlapped by pseudoelement.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov That wasn't OP's condition, this answer will work with solid background perfectly, if OP wanted with `background-image` I would have updated my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Pity that OP's requirements is the only motivation for you to provide more flexible solutions. Regarding solid background I won't say word "perfectly": you'll have to repeat your background-color in pseudoelement. DRY principle is also applicable for CSS and I think it's good to avoid duplicate code where possible.

Comment: I agree with you there is always a better solution for every situation but at that time, this answer worked for OP. If OP wasn't satisfy with this answer I would have either updated my answer or retracted it So a good answer can be chosen.

Answer (score 10):

There are two examples of code: with **CSS** ( + animation ) and **SVG**.

**With animation**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
}

.folder {
  background-color: #d3eafd;
  position: relative;
  width: 92px;
  height: 64px;
  display: block;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

.folder-tab {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.folder-tab:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 10px);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #d3eafd;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.folder-icn {
  padding-top: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.downloading {
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-arrow {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation-name: downloading;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: downloading;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.custom-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  left: -9px;
  border-top: 15px solid #fff;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
}

.bar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes downloading {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  52% {
    top: -110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes downloading {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    top: 110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  52% {
    top: -110%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  
  <div class="folder">
    <span class="folder-tab"></span>
    <div class="folder-icn">
      <div class="downloading">
        <span class="custom-arrow"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**SVG**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="32px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><title/><desc/><defs/><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"><g fill="#157EFB" id="icon-94-folder"><path d="M17,11 L15,7 L4.00276013,7 C2.89666625,7 2,7.88967395 2,8.991155 L2,27.008845 C2,28.1085295 2.89971268,29 3.99328744,29 L29.0067126,29 C30.1075748,29 31,28.1073772 31,27.0049107 L31,12.9950893 C31,11.8932319 30.1029399,11 28.9941413,11 L17,11 Z" id="folder"/></g></g>
  </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Helpful links:

- [More about SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) ( W3C )
- [The Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) ( CSS-Tricks )

Comment: svg is not usable here. requirements are to do it using css

Answer (score 5):

```css
div {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #1e90ff;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(48% 13%, 100% 13%, 100% 60%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 29% 0);
clip-path: polygon(48% 13%, 100% 13%, 100% 60%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 29% 0);
}

/* Center the demo */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

With only a single block level element, you may style a `:before` pseudo-element to create the slanted tab above the containing `<div>`.

```css
div {
  margin: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

div:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -20px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid red;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>content</div>
```

N.b.: This should have a better support on older browsers (and IE) than using a [clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of doing it using the "canvas" of HTML5:

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="cnv" height="200" width="400"></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(100, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(130, 25);
      ctx.lineTo(200, 25);
      ctx.lineTo(200, 125);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 125);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fill();
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using single element and two gradients (one gradient for rectangle, another is for tab):

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 31px, #656d78 31px),
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 32%, #656d78 32%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also this can be achieved via single gradient (for tab) using pseudoelement:

```css
div {
  width: 280px;
  height: 169px;
  background-color: #656d78;
  margin-top: 39px;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -31px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 50%, #656d78 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can insert code, you could use a SVG graphic.

If not, you could draw the vector graphic css `clip-path` as the answer above.
There are some generators, [**here**](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is one I've found

Another option is to use at least 3 divs, skew one using css `transform` in one of them and locating each one using relative os absolute positioning.

Comment: Maybe if you try using an hexagon as basic shape?

Comment: clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);

this is hexagon code for testing the div.. but it is still showing it a rectangle

Comment: yeah I got it man... thanks... I was using Firefox and it is showing it as a rectangle... now i saw on chrome and its polygon Thanks

Comment: Yep, this is not a very recommended method, not all browsers support it. Try svg or 3 divs with one skewed for better compability

Answer (score 0):

You can make polygon's div using CSS.

```
.myDiv {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(48% 16%, 100% 16%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 0, 32% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(48% 16%, 100% 16%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 0, 32% 0);
}
```

Or you can create any type of polygon shape (online) using this website

[https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/](http://%20https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/)